# Svg Circle fill CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Probably a relative simple question but I cant find an answer to it:

Is it possible to fill a circle with a colour to an extent ( with a particular radius) ?
Or have 2 border lines - one coloured and one white with a fill colour ?

```
style="fill:steelblue; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: #8cc63f;"
```

I'm looking to achieve something like this (or similar) in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agv6jr0h/3/):

[image]

Comment: you can do it using `box shadow` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/agv6jr0h/1/)

Comment: Eight, my apologies, I should have prepared an SVG fiddle. Can Your answer be adapted in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/agv6jr0h/3/) ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit from comments:**
As I didn't found how to apply css "background-image" to `circle` elements, I added a way using js.

Or you can achieve this using [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) and here particularly `radial-gradients` :

```js
var svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg')[0],
  r = 30,
  cy = 60,
  nr = r - (r * 0.7),
  c1 = document.querySelectorAll('circle')[0],
  //Assuming you already have those ones

  //first make a copy of the circle you just made
  c2 = c1.cloneNode();

//then apply new styles to the first circle
c1.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "transparent");
c1.style.stroke = "#8cc63f";
c1.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
c1.parentNode.appendChild(c2);

//and to the new one
c2.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red");
c2.style.strokeWidth = "0";
c2.r.baseVal.value = r - nr; //change its radius

//Wrap thoe elements into a single g that will act as one element
var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g');
g.appendChild(c2);
g.appendChild(c1);
svg.appendChild(g)
```

```html
<svg width="720" height="120">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="71%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="40" cy="60" r="30"></circle>
  <circle cx="120" cy="60" r="30" style="fill:url(#gradient); stroke-width: 2px; stroke: #8cc63f;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Im sure there must be an easier way using css than cluttering my js with this..but I guess this will have to do. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do the same with css [radial-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) as well

Comment: could You please provide an example using css for a svg circle ?

Comment: No, I spoke to fast sorry, thought you can do the same to html elements but apparently you can not on inner svg ones. So I updated the answer with a *maybe* shorter way.